# How to understand the security context in "ls -Z"?

Tags: linux, ls, selinux

After referring "`man ls`", it shows "`ls -Z`" can display the security context:

```
-Z, --context
    Display  security  context so it fits on most displays.  Displays only mode, user, group, security context and file name.
```

Executing the "`ls -Z`" command, the output likes this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -Z
-rw-------. root root system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 anaconda-ks.cfg
drwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 backup
```

How to understand the security context: `unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0`? The "`man ls`" doesn't provide the info.

Answer (score 10):

SELinux provides a user (unconfined_u), a role (object_r), a type (user_home_t), and a level (s0). This information is used to make access control decisions. On [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control) systems, access is controlled based on Linux user and group IDs. SELinux policy rules are checked after [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control) rules. SELinux policy rules are not used if [DAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control) rules deny access first.

[This link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) can give you more information for your question.